# Partial transfer when using Nginx

Tags: nginx, iis, windows-server-2016

I have a problem with loading in my website through a Nginx proxy. The website is hosted on a Windows Server 2016 Datacenter server in IIS. When the loading problem happens I have the issue that for example an image won’t load in and I get this error in Firefox in the console "NS_ERROR_NET_PARTIAL_TRANSFER". This also could happen on other files like the main.js. The problem only occurs when the Nginx server is being used together with the Windows Server 2016 Datacenter. Or any other Windows Server release or built. But when I access the site with an IP address directly this problem is gone and it works as expected.

I tried using different Nginx settings but nothing helped (also didn’t make it worse or better). The only thing I could find out is when I host the website on a Windows 10 machine also in IIS (VM on the Windows Server 2016 Datacenter) the problem does not occur. I also tried different Windows Server versions and editions like: Windows Server 2019 and 2022. Both of them I tried in the standard edition and datacenter edition. I disabled on the Windows server 2016 Datacenter the firewall and Windows defender, in IIS any restriction I could find. But on the Windows 10 VM this all wasn’t necessary.

Comment: Enable logging in nginx (error_log directive) and check what is the error on the NGINX side when that happens.